# Index out of range happening from searchBar

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I was following this tutorial on getting a searchBar up and running.

tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

I followed every step exactly as written, but when I run the application on my phone, press the searchbar to begin searching something I run into an error called "fatal error: Index out of range". This is the code that is the entire code that is causing the error

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return users.count
    }else{
        return self.locations.count 
    }
}
```

When I set up breakpoints to see the cause of this error, it shows that when it reaches

```
return self.locations.count
```

that is when the error occurs. I can post more of my code if it will help

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let postInformation = users[indexPath.row]
    cell.userNameTextField.text = postInformation.user
    cell.userDescription.text = postInformation.text

    cell.postImage.loadImageUsingCachWithUrlString(urlString: postInformation.image!)
    cell.cellLocationX = cell.postImage.frame.origin.x   //cell.frame.origin.x
    cell.cellLocationY = cell.postImage.frame.origin.y   //cell.frame.origin.y
    return cell
}

var users = [MapPoints]()
var locations = [MapPoints]()
```

Comment: What is the code for your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` method? How are `users` and `self.locations` defined?

Comment: @MatusalemMarques I updated the question with codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` is always returning items from the `users` array. If `locations` has more elements than `users` it will try to access invalid indices in the `users` array.

`collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` and `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` must read from the same array to populate your collection view.

Have a look at the corresponding `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` in the tutorial you mentioned.